# Spatie/Laravel-Permissions: Dummy Data Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using Laravel with spatie/laravel-permission package as described in this [tutorial](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-54-usesr-authorization-with-spatie-laravel-permission).
However, when I'm trying to create the dummy data, it is returning the following error **Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist  : There is no role named `Admin`.**

Below is the class to generate the dummy data.

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Ask for db migration refresh, default is no
        if ($this->command->confirm('Do you wish to refresh migration before seeding, it will clear all old data ?')) {
            // Call the php artisan migrate:refresh
            $this->command->call('migrate:refresh');
            $this->command->warn("Data cleared, starting from blank database.");
        }

        // Seed the default permissions
        Permission::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Administer roles & permissions', 'guard_name' => 'isAdmin']);


        $this->command->info('Default Permissions added.');

        // Confirm roles needed
        if ($this->command->confirm('Create Roles for user, default is admin and user? [y|N]', true)) {

            // Ask for roles from input
            $input_roles = $this->command->ask('Enter roles in comma separate format.', 'Admin,User');

            // Explode roles
            $roles_array = explode(',', $input_roles);

            // add roles
            foreach($roles_array as $role) {
                $role = Role::firstOrCreate(['name' => trim($role), 'guard_name' => 'isAdmin']);

                if( $role->name == 'Admin' ) {
                    // assign all permissions
                    $role->syncPermissions(Permission::all());
                    $this->command->info('Admin granted all the permissions');
                } else {
                    // for others by default only read access
                    $role->syncPermissions(Permission::where('name', 'LIKE', 'view_%')->get());
                }

                // create one user for each role
                $this->createUser($role);
            }

            $this->command->info('Roles ' . $input_roles . ' added successfully');

        } else {
            Role::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'User']);
            $this->command->info('Added only default user role.');
        }

        // now lets seed some posts for demo
        $this->command->info('Some Posts data seeded.');
        $this->command->warn('All done :)');
    }

    /**
     * Create a user with given role
     *
     * @param $role
     */
    private function createUser($role)
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $user->assignRole($role->name);

        if( $role->name == 'Admin' ) {
            $this->command->info('Here is your admin details to login:');
            $this->command->warn($user->email);
            $this->command->warn('Password is "secret"');
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache
```

Before use Roles or Permissions

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by changing the order of the guards in the config/auth.php file:

This is by default

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

and this is what I have now

```
    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

I found out that I got this error when I changed the default guard to **"api"** (by default it's set to **"web"**).

When you seed roles without changing the order it correctly sets the guard_name to **"api"** but when it wants to apply these roles to a user it probably uses **"web"** guard.

If you are using the default guard and you still get this error just try to set guard_name field in the roles seeder like this

```
Role::create(['name' => 'admin', 'guard_name' => 'web']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue caused by Spatie/Laravel-permission also stores model type in the db and puts the permission on the BackpackUser or User model.

please see this link for reference:

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/issues/193]

the solution is just added on end of 2019 from tabacitu:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/base-about#having-both-regular-users-and-admins

basically you need either to add middleware, either add is_admin column on User or use the middleware provided by tabacitu